# Project Management System (PMS) for a Gaming Company

Tags: untagged

We are gaming company, building several games for Apple and Android platform. For our Programmers, Artist we need project management system.

We are now using redmine for our purpose.

But the `interface of Gantt Chart`, `mailing functionality` and `project deadline interactivity` of Redmine is not fine.

What PMS system will be preferable?

Comment: This is not a question about servers.

Comment: [Shopping questions are off topic on Stack Exchange sites.](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your purpose, interface of Gantt Chart, mailing functionality and project deadline interactivity you can utilize the followings #

- http://www.atlassian.com/software/confluence/
- http://www.activecollab.com/
- http://www.assembla.com/
- http://basecamphq.com/
- http://www.centraldesktop.com/
- http://www.producteev.com/